# Show button if all radio input's value equals yes or alert otherwise

Tags: jquery, html

I have a client that wants me to create a form where the user must check Yes for every question to move forward.

If #Question1 and #question2 = "yes" then show "submit", otherwise alert "You cannot move forward unless all questions are checked yes."

How is this possible with JQuery?

```
<form>
    <div id="question1">
     <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Yes" checked> Yes<br>
       <input type="radio" name="test1" value="no" checked> no<br>
    </div>
    <div id="question2"> 
     <input type="radio" name="test3" value="Yes" checked> Yes<br>
       <input type="radio" name="test3" value="no" checked> no<br>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seemed to work better for me than the other options. Thank-you to all that participated, though.

https://jsfiddle.net/bowtiekreative/42h74hrw/4/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:submit").addClass('disabled').attr("disabled", true);
$( "input" ).change(function() {

var buttons = jQuery("input:radio:checked").get();

    var values = $.map(buttons, function(element) {
        return $(element).attr("value");
    });
    if(values == "Yes,Yes,Yes") {
        alert("both yes");
        $("input:submit").removeClass().attr("disabled", false);
        $(".err-msg").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("input:submit").attr("disabled", true);
        $("input:submit").addClass('disabled').attr("disabled", true);
        $(".err-msg").show();
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look:

```
$('[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  var allYes = true;
  $('[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($("[name='" + $input.prop("name") + "'][value='no']:checked").length != 0) {
      allYes = false;
    }
  });
  if (allYes) {
    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/db0gIw85G3TQakGIotRG

Comment: Tried this on my form. The disabled attribute was removed once you selected any radio value. But doesn't return when the values aren't Yes.

Comment: did you try it on my plunker?

Comment: Yeah it worked, however, it didn't work on the form that I was using on my site for some reason. So I ended up rewriting the code and it worked.

Comment: maybe it's because your "no" was "No"

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. I made that mistake last night. Either way thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
 if($('input[name=test1]:checked').val() !== 'Yes' && $('input[name=test3]:checked').val() !== "Yes") {
    $('input[type=submit]).addClass('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by javascript here is the working example

```
<form onsubmit="return buttonClicked()" action="LoginServlet">
    <div id="question1">
     <input id="qu1Button1" type="radio" name="test1" value="Yes" checked> Yes<br>
       <input id="qu1Button2" type="radio" name="test1" value="no" checked> no<br>
    </div>
    <div id="question2"> 
     <input id="qu2Button1" type="radio" name="test3" value="Yes" checked> Yes<br>
       <input id="qu2Button2" type="radio" name="test3" value="no" checked> no<br>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 <script>
    function buttonClicked(){
        if(document.getElementById("qu1Button1").checked && document.getElementById("qu2Button1").checked){ //checking whether both the yes buttons are checked
            return true;
        }
        else{
            alert("Please select yes for both the questions");
            return false;
        }
    }
 </script>
```